# Character-returning function of unknown length

Tags: string, function, fortran, character, trim

How to use character function of where the result is of unknown length initially?

The `trim()` function, I understand, shows that it is possible not to specify the length of returning string.

For example:

```
write (*,*) trim(str)
```

will return only part of the string without trailing spaces.

This function does not have any idea about the length of returning string before the call.

Or `trim()` function has limitations?

On more variant is to find original code of `trim()` function.

I have found ([Returning character string of unknown length in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141709/returning-character-string-of-unknown-length-in-fortran)) but it is not the answer to my question.

To be sure, I want to write function, that returns string by integer number.

Something like this:

```
function strByInt(myInt)
...
write (strByInt,fmt) myInt; return
end function strByInt

somewhere else:

write (*,*) strByInt(50) ! will write '50'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question you referenced partially answers it. It mentions the allocatable characters with deferred length. See below my implementation I use regularly:

```
  function strByInt(i) result(res)
    character(:),allocatable :: res
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    character(range(i)+2) :: tmp
    write(tmp,'(i0)') i
    res = trim(tmp)
  end function
```

The result variable is allocated on assignment on the last line to fit the answer.

The `trim` function is a different beast, as an intrinsic function it doesn't have to be programmed in Fortran and can obey different rules. It just returns what it needs to return. But it could be as well implemented as above quite easily.

Comment: I found earlier such constructions, but the problem was connected with my use of "Compaq Visual Fortran". Now I am thinking that it is too old for such manipulations. When tried on ifort, that really worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

Fortran2003 has variable character length feature. Here is a sample code.
This program outputs "Beep!Beep!" string.

```
module m_test
  implicit none
contains
  function say2(text)
    character(len = *), intent(in) :: text
    character(len = :), allocatable :: say2
    say2 = trim(text) // trim(text)
    return
  end function say2
end module m_test

program String
  use m_test
  implicit none
  print *, say2('Beep!   ')
  stop
end program String
```

Following line declares variable length character variable.

> character(len = :), allocatable :: say2

You might need "/standard-semantics" or "Enable F2003 semantics" in Intel Fortran.

Comment: Why are many 2003 features turned off by default in ifort? Is it for compatibility or performance? It seems like it causes a lot of headaches (at least for me) that you must specify -assume or -standard-semantics.

Comment: I quite agree. I also hope Intel would implement BLOCK..END BLOCK as soon as possible. BLOCK construct enhances locality of codes (we can even use USE Module feature in BLOCK construct.) And without this DO CONCURRENT cannot work fully.

Comment: You do not need /standard-semantics for deferred-length allocatable in Intel Fortran. You do need it for assignments to allocatable arrays if you want implicit reallocation - that is done for performance reasons. We're discussing making the reallocation default in a future version. BLOCK is coming.

Comment: If the `program String` would use a variable to store the result of `say2`, would I only need to declare it as `character(:), allocatable :: doubledString` and then assign `doubledString = say2('Beep!   ')`? And do I need to deallocate somehow, somewhere to prevent memory leaks or such?