# Fortran wrapper for character functions trim(), adjustl()

Tags: function, fortran, character

I have written a simple wrapper for convenient use of Fortran intrinsic functions 'trim()' and 'adjustl()':

```
character(len=*) FUNCTION trimadjl(str)

character(len=*), intent(inout) :: str

trimadjl = trim(adjustl(str))

END FUNCTION
```

However, I'm unable to use it, since the GNU Fortran compiler fails with the following message:

```
farm_par.f90:633:31:

19    OPEN(iout,file=TRIMADJL(rankstr//fout),access='sequential',status='unknown', &
                           1
Warning: Non-variable expression in variable definition context (actual argument to INTENT = OUT/INOUT) at (1) farm_par.f90:633:22:

19    OPEN (iout,file=TRIMADJL(rankstr//fout),access='sequential',status='unknown', &
                  1
Error: Function ‘trimadjl’ is declared CHARACTER(*) and cannot be used at (1) since it is not a dummy argument
```

The function is declared as external in the header of the subroutine:

```
character(len=*), external :: trimadjl
```

Comment: a bit of an aside, but there is no need to `trim` the string you give to `file=`. Blank padding wont hurt anything. You could as well just use `adjustl` here.

Comment: It won't hurt of course. But I have shell scripts for post-processing that fail if there are blanks in filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Fortran has allocatable deferred-length character strings for this:

```
FUNCTION trimadjl(str)
character(len=:), allocatable :: trimadjl
character(len=*), intent(in) :: str

trimadjl = trim(adjustl(str))

END FUNCTION
```

Such a function cannot be external, place it into a module. See also [Fortran character-returning function of unknown length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460220/fortran-character-returning-function-of-unknown-length)

As @HighPerformanceMark comments, the first error message comes from you marking the dummy argument `str` as `intent(inout)` and then you pass an expression into it. `rankstr//fout` is a compound expression and cannot be passed into `intent(inout)` function, because it is not a variable. Use `intent(in)` arguments in functions wherever possible.

Don't use `character(*)` returning function unless you *really* know what that means **in detail**! Avoid them wherever possible. They are obsolete and very confusing. See "**Assumed-length Character Functions**" in http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Modernizing+Old+Fortran. Don't use them and maybe even forget that they exist.

Comment: I have created a module with the `trimadjl()` function implementation to use in my main program. However, I get another error: `FILE tag at (1) must be of type CHARACTER`. Somehow, the program does not pick up the return type of the function.

Comment: @mabalenk What is `tag`? Without a more complete example I cannot say anything.

Comment: `tag` is the attribute of the file open routine: OPEN(iout,file=TRIMADJL(rankstr//fout),...)
                      1
Error: FILE tag at (1) must be of type CHARACTER

Comment: @mabalenk This is useless, edit your question with a **more complete** example. Including the module.

Comment: I created a simple example to visualise my problem to you and it works. When I use exactly the same sequence of commands in the original source code the compiler fails. I need to check the compiler options before I get back to you.